# Deleted migrations files still migrating

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-migrations

I deleted some of the migration files in my laravel app but after I run `php artisan migrate` command it still migrating the deleted migration files. I already tried `composer dump-autoload` and clearing caches still the same. What am I missing?

Migration sample:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('users');
    }
}
```

Comment: `php artisan migrate:refresh`

Answer (score 3):

Fixed. It is coming from `laravel/passport`.

Answer (score 0):

Run the following artisan commands:

```
1. php artisan config:cache
2. php artisan config:clear
3. php artisan cache:clear
4. php artisan route:clear
5. php artisan view:clear
```

Then run:

```
composer dump-autoload
```

After that run migrate command:

```
php artisan migrate:fresh
```

Comment: still the same, would it be possible that the migration files are coming from a package?

Comment: I don't think so, can you add your migration  table samples

Comment: I only have the default users and failed_jobs migration tables from Laravel. I noticed that all the executed migration files are related to authentications so I'm thinking maybe it is coming from a package that I use.

Comment: Did you run "php artisan migrate:fresh", it will drop all your tables from your database and run your migration tables.

Comment: And also check that which tables you have in your database/migrations folder

Comment: For more details about migration visit: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations